# Handle null string in java

Tags: java, string, null

I am reading CSV file and inserting into table.but when I get completdate as null I want to insert default date.i checked this

```
if(COMPLETEDATE == null){
    css.setString(24, "2013-06-12 00:00:00.0");
}else{
    css.setString(24, COMPLETEDATE);
}
```

Here is the whole function.

```
public void ImportCSV() {
    String csvFile = "C:\\seema\\CSV Files\\2013\\August\\15.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    String PRODLINE,EMPID,EMPFNAME,SHIFT,STATIONID,CURWKDATE,OPCODE,OPDESC,STARTWORKTIME,ENDWORKTIME,PIECECNT,
           BUNDLECNT,PIECERATE,SAM,SKILLLEVEL,DAILYBONUS,NORMALRATE,OVERTIMERATE,WORKDURATION,MONO,DESIGNCODE,
           DESIGNCOLOR,DESIGNSIZE,COMPLETEDATE;

    int i=0;
    try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      try {
        PreparedStatement css = null;
        css= conn.prepareStatement("exec uspInsertEWLProduction ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?");

        String[] country = line.split(",");

        PRODLINE=country[0];
        EMPID=country[1];
        EMPFNAME =country[2];
        SHIFT=country[3];
        STATIONID=country[4];
        CURWKDATE =country[5];
        OPCODE=country[6];
        OPDESC=country[7];
        STARTWORKTIME =country[8];
        ENDWORKTIME=country[9];
        PIECECNT=country[10];
        BUNDLECNT =country[11];
        PIECERATE=country[12];
        SAM=country[13];
        SKILLLEVEL =country[14];
        DAILYBONUS=country[15];
        NORMALRATE=country[16];
        OVERTIMERATE =country[17];
        WORKDURATION=country[18];
        MONO=country[19];
        DESIGNCODE =country[20];
        DESIGNCOLOR=country[21];
        DESIGNSIZE=country[22];
        COMPLETEDATE =country[23];

        if(i!=0) {
           css.setString(1, PRODLINE);    
           css.setString(2, EMPID);
           css.setString(3, EMPFNAME);
           css.setString(4, SHIFT); 
           css.setString(5, STATIONID);
           css.setString(6, CURWKDATE);
           css.setString(7, OPCODE);    
           css.setString(8, OPDESC);
           css.setString(9, STARTWORKTIME);
           css.setString(10, ENDWORKTIME); 
           css.setString(11, PIECECNT);  
           css.setString(12, BUNDLECNT);
           css.setString(13, PIECERATE);
           css.setString(14, SAM);
           css.setString(15, SKILLLEVEL);
           css.setString(16, DAILYBONUS);
           css.setString(17, NORMALRATE);
           css.setString(18, OVERTIMERATE);
           css.setString(19, WORKDURATION);
           css.setString(20, MONO);
           css.setString(21, DESIGNCODE);
           css.setString(22, DESIGNCOLOR);
           css.setString(23, DESIGNSIZE); 

           if(COMPLETEDATE == null) {
              css.setString(24, "2013-06-12 00:00:00.0");
           } else {
              css.setString(24, COMPLETEDATE);
           }
         }
         css.executeUpdate();
       } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
       i++;
     }
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Imported Successfully");
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   } 
}
```

The problem is else part is never get executed eventhough copmletedate is null. Any solution?

Comment: Try to do some thing like this if(null==COMPLETEDATE || "".equals(COMPLETEDATE )){//do something}

Comment: Did you check if COMPLETEDATE is null or just "" (empty string)? It is more likely it is an empty string.

Comment: Can u paste your stack trace here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Commons Utility [`StringUtils.isEmpty(CharSequence)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to check for `null` or `empty` string. BTW, why are you storing dates as string, and not as date?

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(COMPLETEDATE)) {
    // set default date
} else {
    // set COMPLETEDATE
}
```

Comment: I tried using this but getting this error                     error: cannot find symbol
                        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(COMPLETEDATE))      {
  symbol:   method isEmpty(String)

Comment: @seema download and add the apache commons library in your classpath.

Comment: hi rohit can u please share link for that library.i tried commons-lang3-3.3.1 from this http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi site and added jar files but again same error

Comment: @seema It's commons collection, not commons-lang. Here's the link - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/download_collections.cgi

Answer (score 0):

try changing if statement to:

```
if(COMPLETEDATE.equals(""))
```

Comment: this will cause an exception if `COMPLETEDATE` is null

Comment: yes, but if COMPLETEDATE is having null reference, then the try-catch  block will handle it.The program requires COMPLETEDATE 'not to have null reference'.So the if statement in the program,only requires to check for null-value, which is exactly what my answer is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check for null and empty string. Something like this:

```
            if(COMPLETEDATE != null && !("".equals(COMPLETEDATE.trim)))
            {
                css.setString(24, COMPLETEDATE);

            }
            else
            {
                css.setString(24, "2013-06-12 00:00:00.0");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StringUtils.isBlank() which checks for null or empty string.

visit http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

U can do one thing that Compare both thing

```
if(COMPLETEDATE != null || !("".equals(COMPLETEDATE.trim())))
        {
            css.setString(intlength, xyz);

        }
        else
        {
            css.setString(intlength, "Stringdate");
        }
```

May this will help.

and if u Taking loop then try this.

```
if(country[23] != null && !(country[23].equals(""))){
      // set your date code
}else{
    // set String date
}
```

Comment: tried this if part is geting executed eventhough COMPLETEDATE is null.

Comment: @seema haan but if COMPLETEDATE is null then it will store default Date na? so what is still exception? can u just paste your StaceTrace here

Comment: as per ur suggestion if completed date is null it should execute else part.and I don't know what is stacktrace.its my first java program :).I was .net programmer just started with java

Comment: @seema its okey StackTrace is what u getting exception in Console just let me know and i have updated that ans too try that.

Comment: again same.no any change.

Comment: one thing I observed that if I tried this                     String s,t;
        s="null";
        if(s=="null")
        {
             System.out.println("null");
        }
         t=country[23];
        if(t=="null")
        {
              System.out.println("null");
        } with string s its executing print stmt.but not in the case of t.is it bcoz I am reading it from csv file.using string array

Comment: @seema what u observed and paste here that error log. and ya u have declare that int i right and its 0 then why u have put condition if(i !=0) do u thing that it will execute that block. even u have not updated I.

Comment: @seema so try one thing that remove that if(i != 0) block and then try.

Comment: :) I am incrementing that i.I used this becoz I want to read .CSV file heading and after reading heading I want actual data from .CSV file

Comment: @seema ya but see if i=0 at first time then if block will not execute so value will not assign to string so that is why null pointer exception is there. r u getting what i an saying? :)

Comment: @seema just for checking try to remove it once. of change it to if(i==0) so it will execute once so atleast u will have idea. :)

Comment: @seema its just because if u give null value by Default to String then it will not give exception. because u can assign null by default. but when u are fetching from file or DB then u can not assign null. it will give Exception

Comment: u r not understanding the code. as I said I have incremented value of i.  and that's not a issue.the problem is how to handle string null

Comment: @seema u have not updated. do one thing Try to print each element of array of that starting from country[0] to [22] and check.